# Java - Trouble injecting user input into empty array (text-based app for registering products)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to come up with a text-based app for registering and listing items using arrays, but I'm not being successful at creating an empty array and "injecting" information in it. Could you help me out? When I choose option 1 it brings the exception ***"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at AppTrabFinal.main(AppTrabFinal.java:38)"***. I know it is related to empty arrays, but my teacher didn't teach us how to build one without a pre-determined length and I'm lost trying to do it myself. Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppTrabFinal {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, option;
    String[] items = {};
    double[] prices = {};

    System.out.printf("Welcome to the Yellow Submarine store. What would you like to do?\n");

    do {
        System.out.println("\n========= Option Menu =========");
        System.out.println("1 – Register a product");
        System.out.println("2 – List your products");
        System.out.println("3 – Exit");
        System.out.println("==================================\n");
        System.out.println("Choose an option: ");

        option = entrada.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("\nType the name of the product you would like o register: ");
                    items[i] = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter it's price: ");
                    prices[i] = entrada.nextDouble(); 
                }     
                break;
            case 2:
                for(i = 0; i > 0; i++) {
                    System.out.println(items[i+1]);
                }   
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("\nLogging out. Thank you for using our app.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option, try a different number.");
                break;
        }       
    } while (option != 3); 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `String[] items = {}; double[] prices = {};` with no elements i.e. with capacity of `0`. Because arrays are fixed sized.

So you if you know the max size of the array which seems to be `10` from your code then initialize like below:

```
String[] items = new String[10];
double[] prices = new double[10];
```

And if you are uncertain about the max size then you can use `ArrayList` which starts from index `0` and it accepts only `objects`. So, you need to use wrapper classes i.e. for example for `int` use `ArrayList<Integer>`

You can read more [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays always need a predetermined length. Instead you could use an `ArrayList` which can grow. Consider the following code example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.append(42);
list.append(84);
// The list now contains: [42, 82]
list.get(0); // Returns 42
```